# Panel radio buttons selection 1 and change other panel radio buttons ? c#

Tags: c#, .net

i want to make trafic app for that i have to switch between radio button that act like a signals, actually i have 4 panels every panel have 3 radio buttons red , green , orange

Problem: when i select red in any  panel or green other radio buttons must set1  to green or red according to requirment

**Remember their will be only 1 green and all other reds at same time**

i tried to implement code in check change event but if i apply the code on every button this become recursive so create problem i tried that too but not suitable solution

1 event on every radio button

```
   private void R_lane3Red_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  var checkedButton2 = panel2.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
      //                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
      //  var checkedButton1 = panel1.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
      //                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
      //  var checkedButton3 = panell3.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
      //                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
      //  var checkedButton4 = panell4.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
      //                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

      //if  (checkedButton2.Name.Contains("Green")){
      //    R_lane1Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane4Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane3Red.Checked = true;

      //}

      //if (checkedButton1.Name.Contains("Green"))
      //{
      //    R_lane2Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane4Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane3Red.Checked = true;

      //}
      //if (checkedButton3.Name.Contains("Green"))
      //{
      //    R_lane2Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane4Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane1Red.Checked = true;

      //}
      //if (checkedButton4.Name.Contains("Green"))
      //{
      //    R_lane2Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane3Red.Checked = true;
      //    R_lane1Red.Checked = true;

      //}
```

below is image of panel and radio buttons

[image of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLNjU.png)

Comment: Why is all your code commented out?

Comment: I DID ON MOUSE CLICK ... BUT ANY HOW THEIR IS ANY TIMER EVENT AVAILABLE I NEED IT Mean after 1 minutes  buttonchanges them self

Comment: commented refrence becuase this have errors like object refrnece and many more

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating your Traffic Lights as a control. Then you can build the rules into the traffic light control for how it should behave when a specific light is set. Something like the following may work for you:

```
// The event that fires when a light changed, sends notification to the main form.
public delegate void LightChangedHandler(object sender, Lights light);

// Simple enum to pass the state of the TrafficLight around.
public enum Lights
{
    Green,
    Orange,
    Red
}

public partial class TrafficLights : UserControl
{
    public event LightChangedHandler LightChanged;

    protected virtual void OnChanged(Lights light) 
    {
        if (LightChanged != null)
        {
            LightChanged(this, light);
        }
    }

    private bool _changing = false;

    public TrafficLights()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // The business rules for the Traffic Light states.
    public void SetLight(Lights light)
    {
        if (_changing)
        {
            return;
        }

        _changing = true;

        switch (light)
        {
            case Lights.Green:
                radioGreen.Checked = true;
                radioOrange.Checked = false;
                radioRed.Checked = false;
                break;

            case Lights.Orange:
                radioOrange.Checked = true;
                radioGreen.Checked = false;
                radioRed.Checked = false;
                break;

            case Lights.Red:
                radioRed.Checked = true;
                radioGreen.Checked = false;
                radioOrange.Checked = false;
                break;
        }

        OnChanged(light);

        _changing = false;
    }

    private void radioGreen_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetLight(Lights.Green);
    }

    private void radioOrange_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetLight(Lights.Orange);
    }

    private void radioRed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetLight(Lights.Red);
    }
}
```

Then you can add as many `TrafficLights` as you want to your main form. When a light changes in any of your traffic lights, its raises an event to the main form. You can then handle this event and apply the business rules for how the bank of traffic lights should behave. Something like this:

```
    private readonly List<TrafficLights> _trafficLights = new List<TrafficLights>();

    private bool _changing = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add each TrafficLight control on the Form to a list so we can spin through them later and set their state.
        _trafficLights.Add(trafficLights1);
        _trafficLights.Add(trafficLights2);
        _trafficLights.Add(trafficLights3);
        _trafficLights.Add(trafficLights4);

        // Add the handler for the LightChanged event of each TrafficLight.
        this.trafficLights1.LightChanged += TrafficLightsOnLightChanged;
        this.trafficLights2.LightChanged += TrafficLightsOnLightChanged;
        this.trafficLights3.LightChanged += TrafficLightsOnLightChanged;
        this.trafficLights4.LightChanged += TrafficLightsOnLightChanged;
    }

    private void TrafficLightsOnLightChanged(object sender, Lights light)
    {
        // Only allow the first LightChanged event to fire off to avoid the recursive events.
        if (_changing)
        {
            return;
        }

        _changing = true;

        TrafficLights currentLight = sender as TrafficLights;

        // Set the Light state of all other TrafficLights.
        foreach (TrafficLights trafficLight in _trafficLights
            .Where(trafficLight => trafficLight != currentLight))
        {
            LightChanged(trafficLight, light);
        }

        _changing = false;
    }

    // The business rules for setting the other TrafficLight states.
    private static void LightChanged(TrafficLights trafficLight, Lights light)
    {
        // You will need to adjust the following to suit your specific business rules.
        switch (light)
        {
            case Lights.Green:
                trafficLight.SetLight(Lights.Red);
                break;

            case Lights.Orange:
                trafficLight.SetLight(Lights.Orange);
                break;

            case Lights.Red:
                trafficLight.SetLight(Lights.Green);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Adding the `bool _changing` variable allows you to stop the event from recursively occurring. When the first event is fired, you set the `_changing` to true. This will stop further events from firing until you set it back to false once you are done handling the first event.